# CSS3-transition is not rendered properly in Firefox

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, firefox, transition

CSS3-transition applied to two sliding buttons is not rendered properly in firefox, but it rendered gracefully in Chrome and safari.

```
.carousel-inner .item .btn-primary, 
.carousel-inner .item .btn-success {
    -webkit-transform:translate(0,35px);
    transform:translate(0,35px);
    -webkit-transition:all 350ms;
    transition:all 350ms;
}
.carousel-inner .item.active .btn-primary, 
.carousel-inner .item.active .btn-success {
    -webkit-transform:translate(0,0px);
    transform:translate(0,0px);
}
```

See here for complete code:http://jsfiddle.net/zPsWg/

Any thoughts would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Voting to close this old question as the problem can no longer be reproduced :) Also note that the native `transform` property [has been supported since Firefox 16](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d), released in 2012.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to work in mozilla, add browser specified css for mozilla too, as you did for webkit browsers

```
.carousel-inner .item.active .btn-success {
     -webkit-transform:translate(0,0px);  /*  for webkit - chrome, safari */
     -moz-transform:translate(0,0px);     /* for Mozilla  */
     -ms-transform:translate(0,0px);      /* for IE   */
  transform:translate(0,0px);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it still does not work as you can see the updated jsfiddle : [link]http://jsfiddle.net/zPsWg/9/[/link]